# SQL: ORA-00918 column ambiguously defined in INNER JOIN

Tags: oracle

I'm getting this error no matter what I do with the INNER JOIN Statement

Here is my code:

```
SELECT Package_Code, Description, Duration, Site_Code
FROM tbl_Holiday_Details
INNER JOIN tbl_Site_Visted
ON tbl_Holiday_Details.Package_Code = tbl_Site_Visted.Package_Code
INNER JOIN tbl_Site_Visted
ON tbl_Site_Details.Site_Code = tbl_Site_Visted.Site_Code
```

I don't understand what is the problem.

ps. if needed i will provide more code

Comment: When both tables contain a column with the same name then you need to tell the DB which one you mean. Do that by adding the tablename before the column.

Comment: You have `Site_Code` columns in at least two tables. You never clarify which one you want in the `SELECT` column list.

Comment: I am joining 3 tables together and tbl_site_visted is the connection between tbl_holiday_details and tbl_Site_Details

Comment: You say you have three tables, but your example in the question only has two. The second is joined twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that at least `Package_Code` and `Site_Code` exist in multiple tables but your `select` does not specify which table you want to return data from.  Yes, you know that you're doing an inner join on those columns so it doesn't matter which table's value is returned but the SQL syntax doesn't allow Oracle to make that inference.  Generally, I would advise that you always alias every column both so it is clear which table a particular attribute is coming from and so that you don't break code when you add an attribute to a different table that happens to have the same name.

```
SELECT tbl_Holiday_Details.Package_Code, 
       Description, 
       Duration, 
       tbl_Site_Visted.Site_Code
  FROM tbl_Holiday_Details
       INNER JOIN tbl_Site_Visted
          ON tbl_Holiday_Details.Package_Code = tbl_Site_Visted.Package_Code
       INNER JOIN tbl_Site_Visted
          ON tbl_Site_Details.Site_Code = tbl_Site_Visted.Site_Code
```

will work assuming `Description` and `Duration` are defined only in one of the three tables.  I would add aliases to `Description` and `Duration` as well but I don't know which of the tables should be used.  Of course, I would generally use simpler aliases (say, `tsv` for `tbl_Site_Visited`) rather than the full table name.

If you want to avoid aliasing your columns, you could use the `USING` clause rather than the `ON` clause

```
SELECT Package_Code, 
       Description, 
       Duration, 
       Site_Code
  FROM tbl_Holiday_Details
       INNER JOIN tbl_Site_Visted
          USING( Package_Code )
       INNER JOIN tbl_Site_Visted
          USING( Site_Code )
```

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm. Using "USING" is much easier and less complicated.